# Need help asking this question

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630704/how-to-create-a-database-class

I've asked this a [bunch of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629701/should-i-create-a-class-object-or-talk-to-the-database-directly-when-needed-thr) using [different language and on different sites](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228069/should-i-create-a-class-object-or-talk-to-the-database-directly-when-needed-thr) but it either got no response or (this time) downvotes.

It's obviously not meeting some standard but I'd really like to know the answer to it, so how can I improve it?

Comment: Well, for starters, stop reposting the same question over and over again just because you're not getting an answer.  That's the kind of behavior that will get you question banned.

Comment: I delete earlier question before posting new. But I get it now that that's not acceptable.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you deleted it.  It's still unacceptable behavior.

Comment: Why did you delete the one on programmers? That's probably where it belongs, and where you should edit it into shape. Deleting downvoted questions locks them into amber and they can never get the upvotes they need to keep you out of question ban territory

Comment: I was doubtful. (I knew I shouldn't've been). So I've deleted all others and undeleted the programmers and edited it to merge everything. I'll just be more patient this time. Thank you guys.